# Windows 8.1 won't start or repair

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

When I try to start my computer, it just says "iuö|-BOOTMGR" (the text before BOOTMGR varies, and sometimes it is nothing at all, so I don't think it's anything significant) and then there's a blinking cursor (_). When I start with the installation CD and click repair, it thinks the installation is a "Windows Vista (TM) Business (Recovered)", even though it's Windows 8.1 and when I do automatic repair it usually just exists and restarts in the middle of the process, but rarely it gives me an error saying "Could not repair Windows.." and refers to a log file in `\Windows\system32\logfiles\srt\srttrail.txt` Which says something like this (not exact, beacause I translated it from Swedish)

```
Unspecified changes in the system configuration might have caused the problem.

Repair action: Integrity check and repair of system files
Result: Ended. Error code =  0x0
Time  = 394234 ms
```

I tried running a few `cmd` commands like `bootrec` (`/fixboot` `/fixmbr)` and they reported no errors.

I later tried booting into a partition called "EFI boot" which also had the CD icon, and when I ran `bootrec /rebuildbcd` on that, it said that it found a windows installation and asked me if I wanted to add it to boot list, when I typed `y`, it just said it couldn't find that installation. When I tried automatic repair on that, it said it couldn't repair and where the path to the log file is supposed to be (under Log File:) it was empty. After doing this and booting up normally, my screen said

```
222

Press any key to restart
```

With a blinking cursor like this |, instead of _ like before.

Comment: Please provide specifics.  An error message that might be "something similar" is not specific enough to help you with your problem.

Comment: It's not an error message. @ramhound But when I choose automatic repair,  that's what it calls my system, even though it's windows 8.1.

Comment: It was just a small thing, maybe it could help anyway see what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide specfic messages then.

Comment: @Ramhound From where? Like I said in automatic repair it just exists and restarts by itself in the middle of the process, and the commands I ran had no errors.

Comment: Forget it, I can't help you, my first comment was very clear.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, sure. I looked now it said exactly "windows vista wm business". The reason I can't provide any error messages is because I don't get any error messages. The reason I included that was because it was something out of the usual.

Comment: Edit your question.  If it is specifically "windows vista vm business" then say specifically that and lose the "or something similar".  Words of specific meaning, or something similar, is a very specific phrase in my mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31382/discussion-between-ramhound-and-displayname).